# Power BI / DAX - COUNT Frequency of Unique strings/values across multiple columns

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, distinct-values

I have a table with 3 columns like this:

**Table1**

[image]

In PowerBI I would like to count the frequency of each unique value/string and get it in a seperate table like this:

**Table2**

[image]

I'm finding all different ways of getting a list of the unique values like this:

```
Table2 = 
     DISTINCT(
          UNION(
              DISTINCT('Table1'[Column1]),
              DISTINCT('Table1'[Column2]),
              DISTINCT('Table1'[Column3])
          )
     )
```

Which now only gives me a list of distinct values/strings, but not with the count:

[image]

And I don't know how to get the count column with it.

Could someone help me to get the counts with it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using calculated DAX table can lower your performances, depending on the size of your dataset. The easiest way would have been to do the transformation in Power Query: new query based on source table, delete unrelevant columns, unpivot your 3 columns, then you can summarize and count on a visual matrix/table.

Comment: Hi, Yes I know, but it is a small dataset and I would really like to have it in this format... any help?

Comment: Mmh.. Have you tried to use a temporary variable table with the UNION clause you used above then use the SUMMARIZE and COUNTROWS on it ?

Comment: I edit my question to show what I have and where I get stuck. I do have the unique values, but don't know how I can use the COUNTROWS and SUMMARIZE in it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Tabel2 =
VAR T1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tabel1, "UniqueValue", 'Tabel1'[Column1] )
VAR T2 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tabel1, "UniqueValue", 'Tabel1'[Column2] )
VAR T3 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Tabel1, "UniqueValue", 'Tabel1'[Column3] )
VAR T4 =
    UNION ( T1, T2, T3 )
RETURN
    GROUPBY ( T4, [UniqueValue], "Count", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), 1 ) )
```